# What could be a best solution for ElasticBeanstalk environment stop/start for cost saving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-lambda

So i have a use case where we only need Elasticbeanstalk environment only in weekdays and in business hours only. So here at the moment i'm using a lambda function which terminates App environment and later next day other lambda will re-build the terminated environment, but the problem is i have to everyday update ALB dns on route53 recordset so anyone had any similar use cases and got a effective and better solution to this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lambda function itself to handle the [route53 recordset](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets) with the DNS name of the ALB you get when creating it.

Or I might suggest using a CloudFormation template instead to rebuild the environment, including your [route53 recordset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html), and as much as you can automate for it. Even pull the app package from an existing S3 bucket.